# How to perform POSIX shell escapes from Tcl

Tags: escaping, tcl, filenames, sh

**Is there a way to perform POSIX shell escapes on a string from within Tcl?**

*Background:*

I have a list of arbitrary filenames in a Tcl list. I need to expand the list to paste into a shell fragment that will later be executed by an arbitrary POSIX shell (bash, dash, posh, etc) via execing "sh -c".

Here is a example that illustrates the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

set targets {with\ spaces has"stray'quotes has{brackets} $not_a_variable \[escaped_braces\] (not_a_subshell) weird\ \{|#^$(}

set shell_fragment {
  something
  some_command $targets
  something else
}

puts [subst $shell_fragment]
```

The output of the above is the names with Tcl escaping:

```
  something
  some_command with\ spaces has"stray'quotes has{brackets} $not_a_variable \[escaped_braces\] (not_a_subshell) weird\ \{|#^$(
  something else
```

Whereas, what I need it to look like to work correctly is something like this (POSIX shell escaping):

```
  something
  some_command with\ spaces has\"stray\'quotes has{brackets} \$not_a_variable [escaped_braces] \(not_a_subshell\) weird\ {\|\#^\$\(
  something else
```

*Thoughts:*

Here are some ways I can imagine solving this that I don't really want to do:

- In Bash, there is the %q formatter to printf that does what I want. I could exec calls to bash once per filename to take advantage of this facility, but this 1) is a pretty big back, and 2) introduces a dependency on bash, which I don't wish to do.
- Implement the shell escaping myself according to the POSIX shell escaping rules. This obviously would work, but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel. I found an "easy" way to do this by spamming quotes, but this makes debugging terrible and greatly reduces the available command-line length:

Examples of "bad" ways to do it:

```
proc posix_escape_via_bash {name} {
  return [exec bash -c {printf %q "$0"} $name]
}

proc posix_escape_via_spamming_quotes {name} {
  set escaped {}
  foreach char [split $name {}] {
    switch $char {
      '       {lappend escaped {\'}}
      default {lappend escaped '$char'}
    }
  }
  return [join $escaped {}]
}
```

So again: **is there a way to perform POSIX shell escapes on a string from within Tcl?** I would most happy with a "standard" way of doing this if there is one, but I'd also be happy with a non-standard Tcl library, or even a way to do this from C, so I could call it from Tcl.

Comment: That `posix_escape_via_bash` will run into problems if `$name` starts with a redirect character like `>`. `exec` is _strewn_ with pitfalls…

Comment: @Donal good point about the bash-dependent version; that's yet another reason I can't use it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `'`-quote all non-`'` characters *together* instead of individually, and you only need to end and resume the `'`-quoting mid-string to `\`-escape any `'` characters.

So you were on the right track with `'`-quote spamming, because you already realized

1. that single quotes escape *everything* (besides `'`), which reduces the special cases to just one, and
2. that you can just catenate quoted strings in the shell and it interprets them as one string (`'a''b'` parses to the same raw string as `'ab'`).

The last missing piece was that the second point lets us optimize out almost all of the ending and immediately resuming of `'`-quoting which was happening when `'`-quoting each character individually.

So the logic you need is just

1. replace all `'` with `'\''`, and
2. put a single `'` at the start and at the end:

```
proc posix_escape_via_minimal_quotes {name} {
  set escaped {}
  lappend escaped '
  lappend escaped [string map {' '\\''} $name]
  lappend escaped '
  return [join $escaped {}]
}
```

Example outputs:

```
% posix_escape_via_minimal_quotes x
'x'
% posix_escape_via_minimal_quotes xxx
'xxx'
% posix_escape_via_minimal_quotes xxx'xxx
'xxx'\''xxx'
% posix_escape_via_minimal_quotes '
''\'''
```

Answer (score 2):

The key to doing this is to use `string map` or `regsub`.

### Using `string map` to convert a set of characters

All you have to do is to supply a correct mapping for the things you want escaped.

For the specific case you have, the only characters you seem to want quoted are `'`, `"`, `$`, `(`, `)`, `<`, `>` and `|`. Let's add `;`, `*` and `?` too (I'm guessing you don't want stray statement separators or globbing characters). That's pretty straight-forward, but we'll generate the mapping iteratively rather than using a literal:

```
set mappedChars {'"$()<>|&!;*?}    ;#'# Just to deal with SO's formatting...
set escaping {}
foreach c $mappedChars { lappend escaping $c "\\$c" }
```

That's something you'd only need to do once. With that done, applying the map is easy:

```
set escapedTargets [string map $escaping $targets]
```

I'll leave it to you to work out the best way to merge that with your use of `subst`.

### Using `regsub` to convert a set of characters

The other method is to use `regsub` with the `-all` option. This only really works well if you are doing exactly the same type of escaping in all substituted cases.

```
# This puts a backslash in front of all non-alphanumerics
set escapedTargets [regsub -all {[^[:alnum:]]} $targets {\\&}]
```

```
# This _particular_ case has an almost-equivalent-good-enough that's shorter
set escapedTargets [regsub -all {\W} $targets {\\&}]
```

The complication is in determining a correct characterization regular expression for all your problem cases, which is why it's often stated that using regexps turns one problem into two…

---

### Discussion / Alternative approaches

The above map doesn't cover all POSIX shell metacharacters — in particular, it doesn't handle backslash itself or whitespace (doing so would cause you problems since you appear to want to get multiple words) and it should also handle these: `{}[]~` — and the regular expression is perhaps a little bit *too* keen, putting backslashes in front of entirely innocent things. Indeed, some uses (e.g., variable names) require a lot more care than either of the above approaches, as they have things that simply can't be used.

The root problem is that the shell actually has a very complex syntax, with a lot of interacting rules. If you can write your code so as to not require running a shell, you will probably find things far more reliable (modulo the fact that Tcl's `exec` and pipeline `open` have their own bizarre issues that stem from trying too much to be like the shell). Whether this is suitable for you depends on other things that are going on which you didn't tell us in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the great tips! I'm still amazed that there is not a more standard way to do something like this, but at least I've now got several decent ways to approach this in my own implementation.

Comment: The backtick operator (``) could be problematic too if you seek to escape string and prevent security issues.

Comment: I think this answer is good and informative overall. But I want to strongly caution that the approach of exhaustively covering all characters which might be special always entails a risk that we forgot one more special character. It is a whack-a-mole game which never really tells you if you're done playing. For example, even if we only officially support POSIX, in real life users of our code might be using `bash` or `zsh` or some `/bin/sh` which is so close to POSIX that it doesn't even occur to them that there are deviations like `!` or `^` being special.

Comment: Also, I can understand why you delayed covering `[`, `~`, `{`, and so on until the end (because the original question didn't escape or mention them in their example), but I feel like this is a good example of the downside of the approach of covering each possibly-special character (instead of identifying the smallest possible set of rules/cases which covers all characters). I bet the asker _didn't know_ that they wanted `[` escaped from the shell! Because you wouldn't know that's an escaping problem until you've got a file with a name like `e` in your working directory.

Comment: So like, while _you_ might know to exhaustively cover `[` in that situation, the typical result of following the overall approach of "I'm going to handle every special character" (and I've seen this almost universally result in escaping bugs making their way into production code!) is people escape the things they know are special or can quickly discover are special, even though in some cases (Bourne/POSIX shell included!) there *is* an extremely simple way to pass literally any and all characters verbatim through the shell's command evaluation to whatever the shell is passing it to.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a variation of the "quote spamming" method I mentioned, but special cased various classes of characters that either never need to be quoted or can be quoted with a simple backslash. This is still slightly over-eager, but is MUCH better than the original naive approach. In most cases, this gives the same result as the bash printf method.

```
  proc posix_escape {name} {
    foreach char [split $name {}] {
      switch -regexp $char {
        {'}           {append escaped \\'     }
        {[[:alnum:]]} {append escaped $char   }
        {[[:space:]]} {append escaped \\$char }
        {[[:punct:]]} {append escaped \\$char }
        default       {append escaped '$char' }
      }
    }
    return $escaped
  }
```

I'm still very interested if there is a more standard way to do this. It would greatly surprise me if nobody has ever run into this before! =)

Comment: I think my answer represents "a more standard way to do this". I would also say that `printf %q` is not a good standard, because 1) if it was a standard, it would force anyone implementing it into the whack-a-mole game of exhaustively identifying every special character (which the shell itself is in a privileged position to get it right _for itself_, but everyone else has to play catch-up and ideally cover multiple shells), and 2) backslash-heavy approaches have worse human readability and input-size-to-output-size for much more of the possible inputs than what I consider to be "the standard".